# Error in MergeManifest in Unity 5.3.1f1 generating Android Release

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onesignal

I´m trying to generate Android test build to see if Facebook latest (7.4.0) plugin works.

I also have OneSignal to notifications and I got this error on console when

---

```
    stderr[
    Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:16,       .\Temp\StagingArea\android-    libraries\OneSignalNotificationRes\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/receiver[@name=com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver] element:
  <receiver
      @android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
      <intent-filter>
              @android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE">
          <category
--            @android:name="whatevermyapp">
  <receiver
      @android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
      <intent-filter>
              @android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE">
          <category
++            @android:name="${manifestApplicationId}">
]
stdout[
```

---

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to replace all 3 instances of `${manifestApplicationId}` with your Android package name in `Plugins/Android/OneSignalConfig/AndroidManifest.xml` per the [Unity - 3. Android Setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/installing-the-onesignal-sdk#3-android-setup-click-to-expand) instructions.